# ¿Por qué no se actualiza la hora en mi TextView que envío con TimePickerDialog?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un `TextView` que relleno con la fecha y hora que selecciono en mi `DatePickerDialog` y `TimePickerDialog`, el problema es que la hora que elijo en `TimePickerDialog` **no** se actualiza en mi `TextView`, pero la fecha en `DatePickerDialog` sí. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView editTextFecha;
    private int dia, mes, año, hora, minutos;
    private static final int TIPO_DIALOGO = 0;
    private static DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener SelectorFecha;
    private static TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener SelectorHora;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        editTextFecha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextFecha);

        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        año = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        hora = calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minutos = calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        mostrarFecha();

        SelectorFecha = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view,  int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                dia = dayOfMonth;
                mes = month;
                año = year;
                mostrarFecha();
                mostrarHora();
            }
        };
        SelectorHora = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view,  int hour, int minute) {
                hora = hour;
                minutos = minute;
            }
        };


    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case 0:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, SelectorFecha, dia, mes, año);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void mostrarCalendario(View control) {
        showDialog(TIPO_DIALOGO);
    }


    public void mostrarFecha() {
        editTextFecha.setText(dia + "/" + (mes + 1) + "/" + año + " " + hora + ":" + minutos);

    }

    private void mostrarHora() {
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {


                    }
                }, hora, minutos, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo, los pickers están encadenados. O sea, luego de elegir la fecha, actualizás `editTextFecha` y mostrás el picker de hora con esto:

```
private void mostrarHora() {
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                      int minute) {


                }
            }, hora, minutos, false);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Pero como podés ver ahí, no estás haciendo nada cuando el usuario selecciona la hora. Deberías setear los valores de hora en las propiedades de tu objeto y volver a llamar a la función `mostrarFecha`, así:

```
private void mostrarHora() {
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                      int minute) {
                    hora = hourOfDay;
                    minutos = minute;
                    mostrarFecha();
                }
            }, hora, minutos, false);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Algunos comentarios:

- Ojo con la variable `año`, en teoría funcionan los carácteres especiales, pero nunca se sabe cuándo pueden dar problemas.
- No estás usando en ningún lugar `SelectorHora`.
- Finalmente y como un comentario adicional, las variables en Java, por convención, siempre van en minúscula, por lo que `SelectorHora` y `SelectorFecha` deberían empezar con una minúscula también.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya hace lo que quería, también muchas gracias por los consejos, aprovecho y te hago otra pregunta sobre el mismo tema para no abrir una nueva, como puedo hacer para que cuando el minuto sea de 0 a 9 salga así 05 (con el cero delante) y no 5 @malvarez ? Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Me parece que no estaría mal abrir un nuevo tema por eso porque es algo diferente, pero como es corto, te contesto por acá: `String.format("%02d", minutos);`. Si la respuesta te sirvió, no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como aceptada, así le sirve al resto también y nadie invierte tiempo en contestar algo que ya fue solucionado!